# insert into sql statement - asp classic - no value given -

Tags: sql, asp-classic, jscript

I am working with asp classical.
I am trying to take information from the user and then insert into my database.

> the error is "no value given".
>   on line: myCon.Execute(sql);

I think it is coming from my sql statement.

```js
var myCon, myRec, sql;
myCon = new ActiveXObject ("ADODB.Connection"); 
myCon.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Users\\abc.mdb");

var bodyType = parseInt(Request.Form("cbBodyType"));
var education = parseInt(Request.Form("cbEducation"));
var eyes = parseInt(Request.Form("cbEyes"));
var hairs = parseInt(Request.Form("cbHairs"));
var heights = parseInt(Request.Form("cbHeights"));
var religion = parseInt(Request.Form("cbReligion"));
var memberID = parseInt(Session("MemberID"));

sql = "INSERT INTO Profiles (MemberID, Religion, HairColor, Eye, Education, Height, BodyType) VALUES ("+memberID+", "+religion+", "+hairs+", "+eyes+", "+education+", "+heights+", "+education+")";

myCon.Execute(sql);
myCon.Close();
```

---

**EDIT:** The problem is the logic. I have for example table HairColor that has an ID and a Description. ID is a primary key and its foreign key is in table Profile.
When  my user enters the information, i would like to recuperate the combobox value, get the ID and then do an INSERT INTO PROFILES.

Is there an easy way to do it instead of using a lot of "where statement" ?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like  spitting out the `sql` string you generated to see what it looks like? and if you're trying to insert a bodytype, why are you provinding the `education` value for that field?

Comment: I did debugging. I split it and get the exact same error. "no value given"

Comment: I think it is coming from my double quotes

Comment: On what line? At the very least you should be able to pin point the exact line that the exception occurs on. My guess would be its on a `parse` statement where either the Request.Form or Session returns null or empty.

Comment: I edited with the line. I double checked the session and it returns a value

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful The semi colon is because they are using JScript with Classic ASP not VBScript. There is more wrong with this then just that though.

Comment: @NewPassionnate  Have you been able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the use the following variant of code

```
myCon.Execute sql, 0
```

(without parenthesis)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that one of the following is happening:

1. One of the columns you are trying to populate could be a string-valued column.  In that case, you need to surround your value argument with single quotes, as in this simplified-for-clarity example below:

   ```
   sql = "INSERT INTO Profiles (MemberID, Religion) VALUES (" _         
          + memberID + ",'" + religion + "');"
   ```
2. Alternatively, if you have a `- All -` or `Please Select` option as the top and default option in one of your combo boxes, and you haven't specified a value for that option, you could be returning a blank/empty string as a value. That would lead to this as the resulting (simplified-for-clarity) SQL:

   ```
    Sql = "INSERT INTO Profiles (MemberID, Religion) VALUES( 235, );"
   ```

   Note the absence of a value for the second column.  I would have expected you to get a syntax error message instead, though, if that's what was happening.

*Be aware that by doing your SQL this way, assembling a string from posted values rather than using SQL parameters, you are opening the door for a SQL injection attack.*  It's not a good idea.

Comment: My tables have an ID and a Description. 
In my form I am getting the Description value. But I think I just realized where the problem is: In my INSERT INTO statement, I need to get the ID of the description that was chosen. 

Does it makes sense? 

Is there an easy way of doing it?

Comment: How are you creating your HTML `SELECT` tags?  It's possible to specify a description and a value as separate things.  Here's a link:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp.  You'd specify your ID for the `value` attribute of the `option` tag.

Comment: Thank you i will look into it now.  <select name="cbHairs" id="cbHairs" size="1">
                <% while(!myRecHR.EOF) { %>
                <option> <%= myRecHR.Fields("Description").Value %> </option>
                <% myRecHR.MoveNext(); } %>
                </select>
            <% myRecHR.Close(); %>

Comment: You'd want to set up your `option` tags so that what rendered looked like this example:  `<option value="236">Brown</option>`.  Note that the `option` tag has an attribute, `value`.  That way the description will show, but what's returned when the user posts back is the value of the `value` attribute of the `option` they selected.

Comment: So how can i get everything from my sql statement? the value (which is my column id) and the description? 
I found the way below but my problem is when i will want to insert into my sql statement. how do i get only id?                
<option> <% myRecRel.Fields("ID").Value %> <%=myRecRel.Fields("Description").ToString() %></option>

Comment: If you provide a value for the `value` attribute of the `option` tag, the value of `value` will be what's returned when you access `Request.Form("cbHairs")`.  It'll take care of itself. :)

Comment: From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp:  "The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted.

The content between the opening <option> and closing </option> tags is what the browsers will display in a drop-down list. However, the value of the value attribute is what will be sent to the server when a form is submitted.

Note: If the value attribute is not specified, the content will be passed as a value instead."